# Java Keytool - how do I open and keep it open?

Tags: keytool

When I try and run keytool (and I have found many, many versions of it) I cannot get it to stay open, it seems to run something then close.

Heeellp!!

I am using Eclipse on Windows 7 64bit.

Answer (score 0):

Keytool is just a **utility** program to assist in creation/viewing of keystores/private/public keys.

So it just executes a command from the command prompt.

Run the following command to see your options:

`keytool -help`

Read here for instructions on how to use it: [Java Keytool](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/keytool.html)

Comment: Right-o! Bit green with command prompt, but got it now, thanks!